# How to return object in NSubstitute with Substitute parameters

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nsubstitute

I am new to NSubstitute and have previously worked with Moq.
I want to call a function with any arguments and return an object that I create with any constructor args except one that I want to set.

In Moq i can write this:

```cs
new TestObject(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<bool>(), aValueIWantToControle)
```

In NSubstistute I tried:

```cs
var mySubstitute = Substitute.For<IMySubstitute>();

mySubstitute.DoSomething(Arg.Any<bool>(), Arg.Any<string>())
    .Returns(new TestObject(Substitute.For<string>(), Substitute.For<bool>(), aValueIWantToControle));
```

How can i create an object like this in NSubstitute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSubstitute doesn't have any special support for constructor arguments. I think something like the following would work for this case:

```
var mySubstitute = Substitute.For<IMySubstitute>();

mySubstitute.DoSomething(Arg.Any<bool>(), Arg.Any<string>())
    .Returns(new TestObject(default(string), default(bool), aValueIWantToControle));
```